# What is optimized way to write this below code in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

```
$('#form').on('focusout', 'div1 select:last-child', function () {
    nFocusOut(this)
});
$('#form').on('focusout', 'div2 select:last-child', function () {
    nFocusOut(this)
});
$('#form').on('focusout', 'div3 input[type=button]:last-child', function () {
    nFocusOut(this)
});
$('#form').on('focusout', 'div4 input[type=button]:last-child', function () {
    nFocusOut(this)
});
$('#form').on('focusout', 'div5 input[type=checkbox]:last', function () {
    nFocusOut(this)
});
```

Comment: use a common class for all these specific elements

Comment: What's div1 and similar things? It's not valid HTML if it was `<div1>`

Comment: @AmitJoki that's completly right. OP should have provided relevant HTML markup in question. BTW i'm wondering the purpose of `nFocusOut()` method?!

Answer (score 4):

Use **[multiple-selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)**.

> Selects the combined results of all the specified selectors.

**Code**

```
$('#form').on('focusout', 'div1 select:last-child,div2 select:last-child,div3 input[type=button]:last-child,div4 input[type=button]:last-child,div5 input[type=checkbox]:last', function () { 
 nFocusOut(this); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just make it to the below. I suppose `div1` is a class or id, as `<div1>` or something similar is invalid HTML.

```
$('#form').on('focusout', '[class^=div1] :input:last-child', function () {
    nFocusOut(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can use comma seperated list of selectors and pass it to event handler

```
var selector = 'div1 select:last-child, div2 select:last-child, div3 input[type=button]:last-child, div4 input[type=button]:last-child, div5 input[type=checkbox]:last';

$('#form').on('focusout', selector , function () { nFocusOut(this) });
```

**OR** 

you can put `class="someClassName"` for all required div elements and use that class selector to bind event handler so that whenever you need to add or remove element from event handler you don't need to change the jQuery selector
e.g. -

```
$('#form').on('focusout', '.someClassName', function () { nFocusOut(this) });
```

Comment: Does this class need to add on every Last child of div or that particular Div ?

Comment: for every last child of div like for `div1 select:last-child` you need to add `class="someClassName"` to last `select` of `div1`

Comment: happy to help you !! you can upvote and accept this answer if you find this useful